# PSU reverse voltage protection

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, diodes, protection

I bought a lab PSU device and I would like to use it to charge 1.2 V batteries. However the manual says that it's not reverse voltage protected and it might get damaged.
After some research I found out there are some MOSFET modules or IdealDiodes that can protect against reverse voltage back to the PSU. Please see Figure 2, I'm not talking about reverse polarity.
As I am intending to use it to charge low voltage batteries 0-12 V, does any module exist for this that you can connect in between the PSU and the battery? Or what would be the best transistor for this?

[image: Reverse polarity vs reverse voltage]

Comment: if it's a small current you are charging with and want a simple solution you can just use a diode

Comment: Just connect the polarity up correctly. I have been using lab supplies for more than 20 years and as far as I remember I have never once, not ever connected something up with reversed polarity.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Build your own polarity protection yourself. It's fun and cheap. Using a diode is inefficient due to constant current flow through the diode itself and forward voltage drop.